# How can I force hide a div that render on my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I integrate [tlk.io](https://tlk.io/) chat API on my page

[image]

For requirement, my goal is to **hide** that header bar, and keep the rest.

---

I use Google Chrome Tool to inspect, and I got this :

[image]

I also grab this

```
<header id="header" class="header">
  <div class="header-bar">
      <a class="header-avatar" href="http://tlk.io">tlk.io</a>
    <span id="channel" class="header-channel">keystone</span>
    <span class="header-status is-hidden" title="Online"></span>
  </div>
</header>
```

---

I've tried `CSS`

```
       <style type="text/css">
        #header.header-bar{
          display: none;
        }

        </style>
```

---

`JS`

```
<script>
$('#header.header').hide();
console.log('Run');
</script>
```

I got the word `run` to display on the console, but that banner still there.

Any hints ? What did I do wrong ? Is it even possible to do ?

Comment: are you certain the div with id `header` exists when your script runs?

Comment: Why not just use the css `display: none` and target the object in question?  In this case, it looks like you'd need `#header{display: none;}`  JavaScript probably isn't working because an external script is generating the content dynamically.  Either that or this is in an iFrame, and you are unable to change it.

Comment: I'm not sure, how do I check that.

Comment: @AlexanderLozada has the best solution. Just add #header{display: none;} to your css

Comment: You should probably check the license and terms of service agreement with   tlk.io I would be surprised if what you describe doesn't violate the license.

Comment: @bhspencer : I guest, I should do that then.

Comment: @AlexanderLozada : I tried `#header{display: none;}` that header is still rendering. I guess, I can't do it.

Comment: Just tried it, and it still there. I have a feeling that, it load it after the page is loading for some reasons. I'm not sure.

Comment: Nope, the border is not there. Should I tried with the `!important` ?

Comment: Nope,it's a dead end.

Comment: Thanks mate, for trying to help.

Answer (score 3):

The tlk.io embed code appears to use an iframe.

Due to the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), you will be unable to affect its contents.

edit: It *looks* like they let you inject a custom CSS file via their embed tool. Using it to change the interface or remove their branding might get you shut down, though.

[image]

Comment: He could probably go a hacky route and make the iFrame container too small vertically, set `overflow: hidden` and chop off the top, although I don't necessarily recommend it.

Comment: @AlexanderLozada : I hope you don't mind embrace your comment into an answer. I'd would to see your hacky way. :)

Comment: @ihue it's best to keep the branding on the site - they are providing it to you free of charge, it looks like after all.  In response to the hacky solution, I don't wan't to make a formal answer as it probably should be a route you should take, but I uploaded some code onto pastebin that achieves what you're looking to do. http://pastebin.com/8fU7mwc2

Comment: @AlexanderLozada : Thanks, and I totally agree with you all the way. I was just doing this as my requirement said to be, for me, I kind of like the header to be there.